# Magento 2: Apply coupon code programmatically

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon-codes

I want to apply coupon code programmatically when the condition is true. If condition false coupon code should be not applied.

Please help me.

Comment: The most easiest way is to buy this [apply discount extension](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-2-apply-coupon-via-link.html). Once this extension is installed you can simply share the link with your customers by adding valid coupon code as shown below. The link will look like this: ***http://{[siteurl}}/applydiscount/?code={[coupon_code}}&redirect_url={[any_url_of_your_site}}***. If the condition is met, the coupon code will be automatically applied to the cart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this below code :

**Construct Method :**

```
protected $cart;

public function __construct(
  \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
){
   $this->cart = $cart;
}
```

Then, you can use this below code in your function :

```
$cart = $this->cart;
$couponCode = 'your_coupon_code';
if(condition true)
{
    $quote = $cart->getQuote()->setCouponCode($couponCode)->collectTotals()->save();
} else {
    $quote = $cart->getQuote()->setCouponCode('')->collectTotals()->save();
}
```

**Object Manager Method :**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
$couponCode = 'your_coupon_code';
if(condition true)
{
    $quote = $cart->getQuote()->setCouponCode($couponCode)->collectTotals()->save();
} else {
    $quote = $cart->getQuote()->setCouponCode('')->collectTotals()->save();
}
```

**Note : Use construct method instead of object Manager.**

Comment: NEVER EVER object manager! See the full details here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html?itm_source=devdocs&itm_medium=search_page&itm_campaign=federated_search&itm_term=object%20manager

Comment: I will check and update you. Thanks!

Comment: @VasiliiBurlacu Please check my note.

Comment: @RohanHapani how can I check on cart page the condition is true or false.

Comment: Did you use any custom block for cart page?

Comment: I want to always check the condition on the cart page.

Comment: @RohanHapani No, I have not used any custom block.

Comment: Create custom block or viewModel in checkout_cart_index.xml file and use this code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103878/discussion-between-masud-shaikh-and-rohan-hapani).

Comment: @RohanHapani i create the order in programmatically  but couponCode not added

Answer (score 0):

Since the \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart is **deprecated**, better to use this class: `Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface`

**Example:**

```
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;

/** @var CartRepositoryInterface */
protected CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepository;

public function __construct(
   .....
   CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepository
){
   ....
   $this->cartRepository = $cartRepository;
}

public function yourCustomMethod()
{
   ...
   $quoteId = 23422;
   if(your logic here){
      $this->applyCouponCode('your_fancy_couponcode', $quoteId);
   }
}

public function applyCouponCode(string $couponCode, int $quoteId): void
{
    $quote = $this->cartRepository->get($quoteId);
    $quote->setCouponCode($couponCode);

    $this->cartRepository->save($quote);
}
```