# In Magento 2, How to apply Discount code to order

Tags: magento2, orders, quote, discount

In Magento 2, I am Creating order programmatically using this [tutorial](https://webkul.com/blog/create-quote-and-order-programmatically-in-magento2/). I need to apply Discount code(Cart) to order. I am using [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/302582/magento-2-apply-coupon-code-programmatically). But not working. Any other solutions worked out.